# MVC routing when a file actually exists at the specified location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

So I have a route like this in my MVC 3 application running under IIS 7:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "VirtualTourConfig",
               "virtualtour/config.xml",
               new { controller = "VirtualTour", action = "Config" }
               );
```

The trick is that a file actually exists at /virtualtour/config.xml. It seems like the request is just returning the xml file at that location instead of hitting the route, which processes the XML, makes some changes and returns a custom XmlResult.

Any suggestions on how I can tell my application to hit the route and not the actual file in the event that the file exists on disk?

**EDIT:** It appears that I can use `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` in the RegisterRoutes method of Global.asax to tell the application to ignore files on disk. This, however, sets the flag globally and breaks a lot of other requests within the application. For example, I still want calls to /assets/css/site.css to return the CSS file without having to specifically set routes up for each static asset. So now the question becomes, is there a way to do this on a per-route basis?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to achieve this. Why don't you simply move the static file to the `~/App_Data` folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far the best answer to this that I have found is to globally apply `routes.RouteExistingFiles=true` and then selectively ignore the routes I want to pass through to existing files like .js, .css, etc. So I ended up with something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("*.js|css|swf");
            routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

            routes.MapRoute(
               "VirtualTourConfig",
               "virtualtour/config.xml",
               new { controller = "VirtualTour", action = "Config" }
               );
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, I'd like to see it. I'd much prefer to selectively apply an "RouteExistingFIles" flag to individual routes but I don't know if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

No solution here, just an idea.

You can try to implement solution based on your own [`VirtualPathProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) that will provide your own mapping of web paths to file system paths and use default provider for all paths you don't want to take care of.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple solution, certainly if you consider Scott's answer, would be eg: `routes.IgnoreRoute("templates/*.html");`, 
`routes.IgnoreRoute("scripts/*.js");` and `routes.IgnoreRoute("styles/*.css");`.

This gives you both the simplicity of just supplying paths to the RoutesCollection and avoids the work of having to initiate eg. a VirtualPathProvider.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [UrlRewiting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="VirtualTourConfig">
          <match url="^virtualtour/config.xml" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="virtualtour/config" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

NB I'm using this for a different use-case (i.e. serving an angular app from asp.net MVC) - I haven't tested whether MVC routing occurs AFTER url rewriting.

In my case I have a normal MVC route (i.e. `/Dashboard/` => `DashboardController.Index()`) but need all relative paths in the `Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml` to serve static files without getting confused by MVC routing i.e. `/Dashboard/app/app.module.js` must serve a static file. I use UrlRewriting to map `/Dashboard/(.+)` to `/ng/Dashboard/{R:1}` as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Dashboard">
          <match url="^dashboard/(.+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="ng/dashboard/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```