# Adding file to "Content"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# 4 MVC project.

I would like to add a file to my content folder and be able to download it, like https://{myurl}/Content/myfile.txt

That doesn't work. The response is:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

However, https://{myurl}/Content/Site.css does download the Site.css file.

I guess I am missing some sort of dumb configuration, but I am not even sure what terminology to use to search for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it. Instead I added Routes to the Home controller for the files.

So now my site responds to /{myfile.txt} with an Action in the HomeController like the one below:

```
public FileResult GetMyFile()
    {
        return File(Server.MapPath(@"/Content/myfile.txt"),  "text/plain");
    }
```

For just a few files it works just fine. It might be even better (as I could add security or other logic).

Comment: Mark, respectfully I don't think your answer is related to my issue (yes, I do use Server.MapPath, but my issue was not locating the physical path based on the virtual path). Your answer doesn't mention anything about creating an FileResult action in a controller to download the file. Thanks, but I cannot accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- file is geniue not there (i.e. you forgot to add it at all or you added it to project but did not mark as content, in later case file will not be there after deploying the site). Check if file is reall present (should be in the same folder on server as site.css or any other file that works).

  - TXT (or whatever other extension you use) is configured to go through MVC, while CSS is not. Potential fix is `RouteExistingFiles=false` as discussed [MVC routing when a file actually exists at the specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681777/mvc-routing-when-a-file-actually-exists-at-the-specified-location).

Comment: Thanks. The file exists (verified). The RouteExistingFiles=true is actually the opposite situation (still trying some alternatives based on that).

Comment: @rufo, right should be `RouteExistingFiles = false` to serve files as is.

Comment: Yep... I tried it, for some reason it didn't work. I actually liked my solution below better after all. Thanks. +1 for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Map path to resolve virtual paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

And here is an [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath)

Comment: Mark, thanks, but I do not understand what you are implying. I have a file in my server and want to get a fixed Url to download it.